# LaTeX Arial Narrow font

Tags: fonts

I would like to use Arial Narrow font in LaTeX. But I cannot find the package used to do it.

Answer (score 18):

You can use any font installed on your system with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.

```
% Compile with xelatex or lualatex
% source file should be UTF-8 encoded
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Arial Narrow}
\begin{document}
\sffamily Some Arial Narrow
\end{document}
```

Comment: I used `fc-list :outline -f "%{family}\n" | grep "X"` to filter through installed fonts containing `X`.

Answer (score 16):

You can select Nimbus Sans L Condensed (almost identical to Helvetica Condensed/Arial Narrow) like this:

```
\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{mc}\selectfont
```

Comment: Good point! Short question: Latex shows me that OT1/phv/c/n is undefined although I just installed texlive-fonts-extra. Any ideas what's the problem is here? Google didn't help and I know that this worked like a charm on a different computer.