# Hide "real" font name in PDF

Tags: fonts, pdf

Does anyone know how to change the font name listed in the "Document Properties" window of the PDF reader? For example, instead of `A030-Reg-8r`, which is an Arial clone, I'd like to have written `Arial`. I know that this is a bad idea but these are the requirements of my university.

Here is a screenshot to illustrate what I'm talking about.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Ah, bureaucracy, when will you be replaced by productivity? :-)

Comment: I don't think it's possible: the name shown reflects the PostScript name of the actual font used in the PDF. If it's a clone, changing its name would break the licence, the copyright and possibly other laws.

Comment: If you have Arial on your computer, it might be as simple as loading `fontspec` and compiling with `xelatex` or `lualatex`.  See this answer here: [LaTeX Arial Narrow font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20142/latex-arial-narrow-font/20145#20145). Just change the font name to Arial.

Comment: Quite apart from the other points, I'd point out that font names are not really important. Legal reasons mean that the _name_ of a font can be protected but not the _design_. You are being asked to use a particular design of font, so the name should really not matter. (Also, do you _really_ think someone is going to check this?)

Comment: Just only give them hardcopies. Then they _can't_ check. BAM. problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

At least on a simple file it works to use Multivalent to uncompress the PDF, then change the font name, then recompress

```
$ java tool.pdf.Uncompress mypdf.pdf
$ < mypdf-u.pdf sed 's/A030-Reg-8r/Arial/g' > mypdf-fixed-u.pdf
$ java tool.pdf.Compress mypdf-fixed-u.pdf
```

This may be a bit fragile, for example if 'A030-Reg-8r' happens to show up in some image data stream. I believe `QPDF` has a special mode that is supposed to make this kind of manual editing of PDFs a bit easier/more structured, by converting to a format that has a few comments that tools can use to find their way around the document.

Comment: PS I wouldn't recommend this. But you know that. It can't be that hard for you to get hold of actual Arial, can it?

Comment: `pdftk` also can uncompress and compress PDFs. I would keep the number of characters (i.e. bytes) constant. (Not that I recommend to do it this way)