# Can I reduce the number of embedded fonts?

Tags: fonts, pdf

My 63-page document uses four different fonts, Libertinus Sans, Libertinus Serif, Libertinus Math, and Latin Modern Mono. It contains several diagrams with text in Libertinus Sans that were exported as pdf from EazyDraw on macOS and included in the document with `\includegraphics`. The document was compiled with lualatex.

The output from `pdffonts` is surprisingly long:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
CWZDXV+LibertinusSans                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    369  0
MXGPBS+LibertinusSans-Bold           CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    370  0
NSYELB+LibertinusSerif               CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    371  0
RVIWPZ+LibertinusSerif-Bold          CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    379  0
MAOXEN+LibertinusSerif               CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    598  0
KAGWZQ+LibertinusMath                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    599  0
VCISJI+LibertinusSerif-Italic        CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    600  0
EFAXXN+LibertinusMath                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    602  0
RNBUFH+LibertinusMath                CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes    603  0
VBIWWB+LibertinusSans-Bold           Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     698  0
MUMYST+LibertinusSans-Bold           Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    699  0
DUOXMP+LibertinusSans                Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     808  0
NCEJUC+LibertinusSans                Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    809  0
LYNSIX+LibertinusSans-Bold           Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     810  0
NTVMVU+LibertinusSans-Bold           Type 1C           Custom           yes yes yes    811  0
MJECAE+LibertinusSans                Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     918  0
QPGWDK+LibertinusSans-Bold           Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     919  0
RDXTEN+LibertinusSans                Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     950  0
KRZEVX+LibertinusSans-Italic         Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     951  0
SQHTTE+LibertinusSans                Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     990  0
YGNTDE+LibertinusSans-Bold           Type 1C           MacRoman         yes yes no     991  0
BFRXXX+LMMono12-Regular              CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes   1018  0
QOOYEH+LMMono10-Regular              CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes   1251  0
```

Questions:

1. Why does the same font/type/encoding combination (e.g. LibertinusSerif/CID Type 0C/Identity-H) appear twice? Different font sizes perhaps?
2. The different combinations of LibertinusSans with type/encoding seem to be related to the diagrams being included. Is there are a way to "reencode" things to make fonts more consistent?

Comment: This is a consequence of subsetting, and is not unique to TeX. The funny-looking code before the font name is an internal label, which describes the subset. Also, if LuaLaTeX (via fontspec) loads a font with different properties, it may be treated as different subsets. For example, according to the fontspec manual, loading a font with different inter-word spacing will do that.

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/156429/5763