# Fonts: Arial Narrow (or equivalent)in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, packages

I may be opening an old wound here...my University's preferred font is Arial Narrow.  I have very little experience with working with fonts; I usually stick with CMR, which at least provides a perfect match across the entire document; mathematics and all.

However, back to Arial Narrow.  My first attempt was to put

```
\fontfamily{phv}\fontseries{mc}\selectfont
```

(following the instructions at [LaTeX Arial Narrow font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20142/latex-arial-narrow-font)) straight after `\begin{document}`; this typeset the body of the text beautifully, but kept sections headings in cmr bold.  I tried to download all the nonfreefonts with `getnonfreefonts` but for some reason they all ended up in the wrong directory.

I tried using `\usepackage{helvet}` which certainly works across the entire document, but gives me an ordinary, not narrow, font.  I'll try using `\usepackage{uarial}` once I move that new font tree out of `/usr/local/share/texmf` and into `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/`.

But if there's any better, or more straightforward way...?

Comment: Actually, I've discovered that if I add the lines `\usepackage{fontspec}` and `\setmainfont{Liberation Sans Narrow}` and compile with `xeLaTeX` I get precisely the effect I want.

Comment: For PDFTeX way, PTSansNarrow comes pretty close. See this for an application http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67586/how-to-create-comparison-tables-in-latex

Comment: Relevant to a part of the problem: How do I change the font of my headings: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1455/1860

Comment: The various parts of the question have been covered before, as the comments show. As you did get Arial Narrow working for the body, the question about sorting sections would seem to be what's needed to get fully on-track, so I've duped.